# Hibernate substring in where clause

Tags: java, hibernate

I am starting with Hibernate,
I have following code:

```
public List<Table> getDaoByDate(Date valDate, boolean checkPast, Class daoClass)  {
     EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    CriteriaBuilder builder = factory.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(daoClass);
    Root table = criteriaQuery.from(daoClass);
    criteriaQuery.select(table);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");

    String[] let = { "A", "B", "CD", "D", "DB", "DN", "DR", "DV", "E", "ER", "H", "J", "K", "KR", "L", "M",
            "N", "Q", "RE", "S", "W", "Z" };
    List<String> valuesErtae = Arrays.asList(let);

    In<Object> inLet = builder.in(table.get("let"));

    for (String value : valuesErtae) {
        inLet.value(value);
    }

    Predicate globalRestr = inLet;
    if (!checkPast) {
        In<Object> inAnnouncement = builder.in(table.get("FirstDate"));
        inAnnouncement.value(sdf.format(valDate));

        globalRestr = builder.and(globalRestr, inAnnouncement);
    }
    globalRestr = builder.and(globalRestr,  builder.lt(builder.concat(builder.concat( builder.substring(table.get("TestDate"), 5, 4), builder.substring(table.get("TestDate"), 3, 2)), builder.substring(table.get("TestDate"), 1, 2)).as(Number.class), 20180219));

    criteriaQuery.where(globalRestr);

    TypedQuery q = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

    List<Table> dao = null;
    try {
        dao = q.getResultList();

        ...
```

after I added 
 globalRestr = builder.and(globalRestr,  builder.lt(builder.concat(builder.concat( builder.substring(table.get("TestDate"), 5, 4), builder.substring(table.get("TestDate"), 3, 2)), builder.substring(table.get("TestDate"), 1, 2)).as(Number.class), 20180219));

getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '.' near line 1, column 501
```

What I want to achieve is :

```
and substring(TestDate, 5,4)+ substring(TestDate, 3,2)+ substring(TestDate, 1,2) < '20180312'
```

what should be proper way to add this condition?
thx

Comment: try update from .as(Number.class), 20180219)); to .as(Integer.class), 20180219));

Comment: it didn't help, I solved it with native query, but still wondering if there is a way how to do it without it

Comment: I reproduced similar case like yours, same error occur and I found the hql generated by hibernate end with "cast(substring(,,,,, as java.lang.Number)<20180219" and result the same error as yours. After changing to what I suggest, the hql changed to "cast(substring(,,,,, as integer)<20180219" and no problem occur I use Oracle database and hibernate 4.1.4, hope this can help.